# Why is a view slower than a subset table that is kept up to date by a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, view, triggers

I'm working on a large sql server database with millions of records with dates. 
I have a select query that is interested in records with a date that is between today and last week and manipulates this data counting its rows and making calculations.

The query:

```
SELECT ( totaleAttivazioniConsumer.totale - totaleDisattivazioniConsumer.totale ) AS 
       Utenti_Attivi, 
       totaleAttivazioniConsumer.timestamp, totaleAttivazioniConsumer.tipo
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS totale, timestamp, tipo
        FROM   andamentoSettimanaleAttivazioni 
        GROUP  BY timestamp, tipo
        HAVING timestamp = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND tipo = 'Consumer') AS 
        totaleAttivazioniConsumer 
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS totale, 
                    timestamp, tipo
             FROM   andamentoSettimanaleDisattivazioni 
             GROUP  BY timestamp, tipo 
             HAVING timestamp = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND tipo = 'Consumer') AS 
                                    totaleDisattivazioniConsumer
        ON totaleAttivazioniConsumer.timestamp = totaleDisattivazioniConsumer.timestamp
UNION ALL
SELECT ( totaleAttivazioniCorporate.totale - totaleDisattivazioniCorporate.totale ) AS 
       Utenti_Attivi, 
       totaleAttivazioniCorporate.timestamp, totaleAttivazioniCorporate.tipo
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS totale, timestamp, tipo
        FROM   andamentoSettimanaleAttivazioni 
        GROUP  BY timestamp, tipo
        HAVING timestamp = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND tipo = 'Corporate') AS 
        totaleAttivazioniCorporate 
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS totale, timestamp, tipo
              FROM   andamentoSettimanaleDisattivazioni 
              GROUP  BY timestamp, tipo 
              HAVING timestamp = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND tipo = 'Corporate') AS 
              totaleDisattivazioniCorporate
        ON totaleAttivazioniCorporate.timestamp = totaleDisattivazioniCorporate.timestamp
UNION ALL
-----snip-----
-----same code but CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
-----goes down to CAST(DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE) and it UNION ALL
```

*I'm sure the query could be optimized but that's not the question I'm asking.*

Everytime this query gets executed it takes a considerable amount of time.
I tried creating a view with only records that have a date `>= today - 7 days` and then executing the query FROM that view. The execution time improved by more than 70% but it still wasn't fast enough for my client.

So, I tried to create a (I call it subset table because I'm unaware of a better name) table with data where its date is `>= today - 7 days`. This table is kept up to date by a trigger that simply adds to it the new data when it is inserted in the original table. The behaviour is very similar if not identical to a view AFAIK except that it is stored on disk (right?).
Running that query from this table made it istantaneous compared to running it on the original or even the view.

Why is the *subset* table faster than the view?

Is a *subset* table always faster than a view if space is not a concern?

Comment: A view is just a saved query, unless you add an index to the view, the view performs exactly the same as the query inside the view. A separate table with less rows will of course perform much better as there is less data to read.

Comment: You could add a filtered index on your primary table to speed up the query without needing a second table. This is doing something very similar to your trigger, just using built in tools to do it.

Comment: Views can get expensive.  Perhaps you should consider a Table-Valued Function where you pass parameters as filters